# How to select element with specific string with awk

Tags: linux, awk

There is the example with two lines as below, but the real data have many lines. I want to only pick the taxa ending with 'viridae' in linux, maybe with awk. The order number of this kind of string/word is different if splitting by ";", like Orthomyxoviridae as 8th, and Solemoviridae as 7th.

```
Viruses; Riboviria; Orthornavirae; Negarnaviricota; Polyploviricotina; Insthoviricetes; Articulavirales; Orthomyxoviridae; Alphainfluenzavirus

Viruses; Riboviria; Orthornavirae; Pisuviricota; Pisoniviricetes; Sobelivirales; Solemoviridae; Polerovirus
```

May I ask how to achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F';' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~"viridae") print $i}' file
```

And if you want to strip the leading or training spaces:

```
awk -F '[ \t]*;[ \t]*' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~"viridae") print $i}' file
```

---

Question: *if no match, how to add one NA to this row?*

```
awk -F '[ \t]*;[ \t]*' '{
    f=0
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~"viridae$") {f=1; print $i}
    if (!f) print "N/A"
}' file
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask if no match, how to add one NA to this row?

Comment: Can the code be in one line? Thanks

Comment: @Bio_farmer any code in almost any language can be all in one line - just read the man page to find what separates statements in that language, add those and then cram it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Why `awk`? This is what `grep` has been written for :-)

I have created following file:

```
Prompt> cat test.txt
first latest nogeentest testament blabla
toet toet
```

I want to see all words, ending with the word "test":

```
Prompt> grep -o "[a-z]*[a-z]test" test.txt
latest
nogeentest
```

I want to see all words, containing the word "test":

```
Prompt> grep -o "[a-z]*test[a-z]*" test.txt
latest
nogeentest
testament
```

You might be helped with:

```
Prompt> grep -o "[a-z]*[a-z]viridae" test.txt
```

Have fun!

For your information: `[a-z]*[a-z]` means "any number of letters, followed by any letter", which can sometimes be replaced by `[a-z]+`. However, on my system this does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks, may I ask if no matching, how to add "NA" to this line? Thanks

Comment: ...and also, how to deal with UpperCase?

Comment: In case you want case insensitive, you just use the `-i` switch next to the `-o`.